# How to print a file to the XpsDocumentWriter in C# or better yet, via VS.NET Automation?

Tags: c#, printing, xps

What I am trying to accomplish (the manual way)

In VS 2010, I have project items that are sequencediagrams, they are really just .xml and have a suffix of .sequencediagrams .  So I open the diagram in VS and go to File->Print .  Now I do not select a physical printer in the dropdown, I change that to Microsoft XPS Document Writer, because I want an outputed .XPS file.

How to do in code ?

I am trying to do this in C# code, specifically in a VS add-in (automation).  So what I have is a handle to a projectinfo, which gives me the full path of the file, but I am kind lost in the *print* part of it.  I thought I could use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.xps.xpsdocumentwriter.aspx , but the method signatures don't seem to take a simple document path.

Anyone have experience in this? suggestions?   Thanks.

Comment: I don't think the XPSDocumentWriter knows how to render a sequencediagram

Comment: @Henk - O.k., to oversimplify, I need to send an arbitrary file to the printer 'Microsoft XPS Document Writer' .

Comment: No, you don't send files to a(ny) printer, you print to it.

Comment: @Henk - I understand that, I don't know how to edit comments, I forgot the word _driver_ after printer.  You need the MS XPS print driver to print to XPS file (not an actual printer).

Answer (score 0):

It was suggested to look at these links:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/camerons/archive/2010/03/08/save-a-diagram-to-image-file.aspx

http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/09/03/visual-studio-extension-save-uml-diagram-as-image.aspx

by Ryan Molden (MSFT)

Thanks to Ryan, bypassing the whole diagram -> XPS step is great.